# how to insert values entered in datagridview into database table?

Tags: c#

I want to insert the numbers entered in a datagridview to a database table.
Whenever I do this, only 0 is entered in the table no matter whatever number is entered in the datagridview. Here is my code..

```
decimal num=Convert.ToDecimal(amountdataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["amountColumn"].Value);
cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Deposit values('" + num + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Do you want to store 1 value or all values in the datagridview?

Comment: Does your table Deposite only have one column?

Comment: only 1 value from a particular row.. table consists of only 1 column

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the single quote and **num** to `String` using `ToString()`:

```
cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Deposit values('" + num + "')", con);
```

So, that it would become

```
cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Deposit values(" + num.ToString() + ")", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure num is not null before inserting into database and try to remove the quotes around the value in the insert statement :

> cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Deposit values( " + num + ")", con);

And also try to output your sql statement and manualy insert it yourself to see if the insert is ok like:

> MessageBox.Show("INSERT INTO Deoposit VALUES("+num+")");

Hope this helps.

Comment: its still not working.. when i enter the value of  num as 100, the value entered in the table is 0.

Comment: Your table has any other columns, do you have some validation on the database side? What database are you using ? And what type is the Deposit column?

Comment: im using ms sql server compact edition 3.5 . column is a float datatype.. there is only 1 column in the table..

Comment: try to change from float to decimal datatype because decimal requires more storage space.

Answer (score 0):

try 'Text' instead of 'Value', I tried this and it works:
SearchResultGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text

note that Convert return 0 if amountdataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["amountColumn"].Value be null. did you check if your value is correct?

Comment: i checked the value of num. its always null. is there any problem in convertion..?

Comment: did you try replacing "amountColumn" with an index (like 0)? replace "amountColumn" with your cell index and try again.

Comment: i hav only one cell.. then cell index will be 0. isn't it..?